# Are the concessions/permissions given by Paul in 1 Corinthians 7 binding to other churches?

Tags: 1-corinthians

(KJV)1 Corinthians 7:5-6

> Defraud ye not one the other, except it be with consent for a time, that ye may give yourselves to fasting and prayer; and come together again, that Satan tempt you not for your incontinency. [6] But I speak this by permission, and not of commandment.

(KJV)1 Corinthians 7:12

> But to the rest speak I, not the Lord: If any brother hath a wife that believeth not, and she be pleased to dwell with him, let him not put her away.

Paul gives these concessions/permissions in reply to a letter the Corinthians had written him, Since these concessions/permissions which were not commandments concerned the church at corinth,should they be binding to other churches?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'Defraud' from Scriveners Textus Receptus is ἀποστερεῖτε apostereite, which would be *do wrong* or *deprive*.

In 1 Corinthians 7:1 Paul identifies what the Corinthians wrote to him

> It is good for a man not to touch a woman.

In 7:2 Paul responds to that statement

> Nevertheless, to avoid fornication, let every man have his own wife, and let every woman have her own husband.

In 7:3-4 Paul describes what that should look like

> Let the husband render unto the wife due benevolence: and likewise also the wife unto the husband. The wife hath not power of her own body, but the husband: and likewise also the husband hath not power of his own body, but the wife.

In 7:5-6 Paul clarifies the limitations

> Defraud ye not one the other, except it be with consent for a time, that ye may give yourselves to fasting and prayer; and come together again, that Satan tempt you not for your incontinency. But I speak this by permission, and not of commandment.

So is this for all or just the church of Corinthians?

2 Timothy 3:16

> All scripture is given by inspiration of God, and is profitable for doctrine, for reproof, for correction, for instruction in righteousness:

So as much as any of 1 Corinthians applies to all believers/churches, so would this "permission". In as much that none should deprive their spouse "except it be with consent for a time".